# Extract the value out of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I'm trying to extract information from a Promise returned by a fetch call. I don't seem to be able to do this. Either I get an `undefined` or I get another Promise, rather then the actual content of the promise itself. For example:

```js
     async function fetchCoordinates(pluscode) {
       let response = await fetch(url.replace("${pluscode}", pluscode));
       return await response.json();
     }
     
     function getCoordinates(pluscode) {
       let geoinfo;
       fetchCoordinates(pluscode).then(info => {geoinfo = info})
       return geoinfo
     }
   
     geoinfo = getCoordinates("{{ place.pluscode }}");
```

When evaluated, geoinfo is `undefined` (instead of an object). However, if I change this line:

```
fetchCoordinates(pluscode).then(info => {geoinfo = info})
```

to:

```
fetchCoordinates(pluscode).then(info => {console.log(info)})
```

Then the object is saved logged correctly to the console.

Comment: You extract the value by using `await`. Or chain a `.then()`. Once a value is a promise, you must treat it as a promise forever.

Comment: I'm using await and still it doesn't work. @VLAZ At some point I want to store the information of fetch into a variable and I seem unable to do that.

Comment: @EdgarDerby async functions *always* return a promise. Just because you've used `await` in an async function doesn't mean it produces a plain value. It is not possible to convert async code to synchronous one like you've tried with `return await`.

Comment: I continue not to understand and now that the question is closed I can't even get more information about my specific case. :( The questions linked above do not help...

Comment: @EdgarDerby The questions linked above explain the general case. Try to understand them! You're right, it is impossible to synchronously extract the information, you always get another promise. Use it like a promise.